# Error when trying to edit a product

Tags: product, error

I have this error when I try to click on a product in admin:

```
2016-08-29T10:37:38+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Productslider/Model/Source/Feature.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/blueb/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-08-29T10:37:38+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Productslider/Model/Source/Feature.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/blueb/public_html/app/code/local:/home/blueb/public_html/app/code/community:/home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core:/home/blueb/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php')  in /home/blueb/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

I think I have made no changes. I didn't install any new extension. Yesterday I have edited products with no error and today the error is there.

Thanks for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably uninstalled a module operating on Magento EAV.

From your error I suppose it was a `Productslider` feature.

You have to open MySQL table `eav_attribute` and manually delete the attribute line containing `mage_productslider/source_feature` in the `source_model` column.

This should work (?):

```
delete from eav_attribute where source_model='mage_productslider/source_feature'
```

If it does not work just locate the attribute and delete it manually.

Comment: Thanks for you help. MySQL dont work but i search and deleted it manually.

Now I can edit products

thanks

Comment: You are welcome, pls mark as correct answer.